# Inserting character after every nth element of a string (not using stringstream)

Tags: c++, string, stl, iterator, stringstream

I've written a function that removes spaces and dashes from a string. It then inserts a space after every 3rd character. My question is can anybody suggest a different way to do this not using `stringstream`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string FormatString(string S) {

    /*Count spaces and dashes*/

    auto newEnd = remove_if(S.begin(), S.end(), [](char c){return c == ' ' || c == '-';});
    S.erase(newEnd, S.end());

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << S[0];

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < S.size(); i++) {
        if (i%3==0) {ss << ' ';}
        ss << S[i];
    }

    return ss.str();
}

int main() {

    std::string testString("AA BB--- ash   jutf-4499--5");

    std::string result = FormatString(testString);

    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why? What's wrong with using `std::stringstream`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm just curious if there is another way to do it just using iterators and `std::string::insert`? I couldn't figure it out? Thanks

Comment: There are other ways to do it, but they are way more complex and error prone. Using an input string stream or `std::string::insert` are simple and straight-forward. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the input string as the output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string FormatString(string S) {
    auto newEnd = remove_if(S.begin(), S.end(), [](char c){return c == ' ' || c == '-';});
    S.erase(newEnd, S.end());

    auto str_sz = S.length();
    /* length + ceil(length/3) */
    auto ret_length = str_sz + 1 + ((str_sz - 1) / 3);
    S.resize(ret_length);

    unsigned int p = S.size()-1;
    S[p--] = '\0';
    for (unsigned int i = str_sz-1; i>0; i--) {
        S[p--] = S[i];
        if (i%3 == 0)
            S[p--] = ' ';
    }

    return S;
}

int main() {
    std::string testString("AA BB--- ash   jutf-4499--5");

    std::string result = FormatString(testString);

    cout << result << endl;
    // AAB Bas hju tf4 499 5
    return 0;
}
```